# I was checking my log of netguard ... and then I saw this ... is normal?

Tags: google-play-store

I was checking my log of netguard ... and then I saw this ... now im freaked[image]

Answer (score 1):

ampproject.org is the website for the Amp project developed by Google and it is normal.

“Amp is a web component framework and a website publishing technology developed by Google which has the mission to provide a user-first format for web content"

Comment: +1 it would be even better if you post the source link.